# Basic Authentication in Spring Security( authentication failure message)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am developing website(HTML, javascript, jQuery, Ajax, css) in which, I am using basic authentication in spring in server side. 
I am sending Basic="Base64 Endcoded Username & password" in Authorization header of HTTP request.
Login works fine on correct username & password.
But on failure, it shows me a default prompt to enter a username & password. 
What can I do to so that prompt is not shown, Instead I should get a error code.
So that, I can display proper failure message.

---

Spring Security

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

```
<http create-session="never"> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/user*" access="ROLE_USER" /> 
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
    <http-basic />
</http> 

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
            users-by-username-query="
                select UserName as username, Password as user_password,true 
                from User where username=?" 

            authorities-by-username-query="
                select UserName as username,'ROLE_USER' from User where username=?" 

        />
    </authentication-provider>

</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: are you using the <form-login> tag in the xml file? And in the logs are you getting an authentication failure error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much of hurdle .. finally I have done it.

I have posted it on my blog

http://swapgo20.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/website-spring-security-basic-authorization-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

By default, the class `AuthenticationEntryPoint` redirects user to the login page when there is a failure in the authentication process. To change the default behavior and provide a custom Authentication Failure page, you can specify an entry in your security.xml file

```
<form-login login-processing-url="your-login-check" login-page="/login"
            username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
            authentication-failure-url="/login/authenticationFailure" />
```

That should be it! You'll get redirected to the page specified in the `authentication-failure-url` attributte in the xml.

Comment: I am not using form login. I am sending authorization header in http request to server which is using spring security.

Comment: yes.. i meant in form-login tag in the spring security xml file in the server.

Comment: No, I am not using form login.

Comment: Then how have you configured spring security? Please update question with those details.